# Hadamard pattern question

Tags: java, recursion

I am writing a program that displays Hadamard pattern using recursion.

A 1-by-1 Hadamard pattern is a single black square. In general a 2N-by-2N Hadamard pattern is obtained by aligning 4 copies of the N-by-N pattern in the form of a 2-by-2 grid, and then inverting the colors of all the squares in the lower right N-by-N copy.

I would like to produce the same picture as  [this one](http://img5.imageshack.us/img5/2062/hadamardy.jpg)

My code is:

```
import java.awt.*;

import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Hadamard extends JPanel{


@SuppressWarnings("unused")
private void hadamard(Graphics g, int n, int x, int y, int width, int height){

    if(n == 0){

        g.fillRect(x/2, y/2, width, height);
        return;
    }
    else{

        hadamard(g, n-1, x, y, width/2, height/2);

        hadamard(g, n-1, x + width, y,  width/2, height/2);

        hadamard(g, n-1, x, y + height, width/2, height/2);

        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        hadamard(g, n-1, x + width, y + height, width/2, height/2);
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);


    }
}

protected void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponent(g);

    hadamard(g, 2, getWidth() / 2, getHeight() / 2, getWidth() / 2, getHeight() / 2);

}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Hadamard panel = new Hadamard();
    JFrame app = new JFrame();

    app.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    app.add(panel);
    app.setSize(516, 538);
    app.setVisible(true);

}
```

}

I don't change properly the colors of the squares in the lower right corner. I've been stuck at this step for the last a couple of hours and am hoping someone would give me an idea how to do it correctly because I don't know.

Thank you in advance.
Nath

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is not *inverting* the lower-right quadrant, it's simply *forcing* it to be white.

I would say that the best solution is to add an extra parameter to your recursive method (let's call it `b`), whose value can be `true` or `false`.  You can then recurse as:

```
    hadamard(g, n-1, x, y, width/2, height/2, b);
    hadamard(g, n-1, x + width, y,  width/2, height/2, b);
    hadamard(g, n-1, x, y + height, width/2, height/2, b);
    hadamard(g, n-1, x + width, y + height, width/2, height/2, !b);
```

Then when you get to the `fillRect` calls, choose white or black depending on the value of `b`.

Comment: @Oli Following your advice I changed my code:`                                   private void hadamard(Graphics g, int n, int x, int y, int width, int height,boolean b){
    
    if(n == 0){
 if(b==true)
   g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
 else
   g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
 g.fillRect(x/2, y/2, width, height);
 return;
 }
 else{
 hadamard(g, n-1, x, y, width/2, height/2, true);
   
 hadamard(g, n-1, x + width, y,  width/2, height/2, true);
   
 hadamard(g, n-1, x, y + height, width/2, height/2, true );
   
 hadamard(g, n-1, x + width, y + height, width/2, height/2, false);
            
  }
 }`

Comment: @Nath: That still won't work.  You are hard-coding the value of `b` on the recursive calls!

Comment: @Oli How can I format my code in readable format? I used `code` but the code is not like block-type.

Comment: @Nath: If you are writing in a comment, you can put code in-between backticks.  But I recommend editing your question to incorporate your new code.

Comment: @Oli - I got it. I've fixed the code. It works great. Thank you very much for your help, Oli. I appreciate it.

Comment: @Oli - So far instead of `boolean` parameter I was using a flag  /counter in my code, which was being set depending on the case. But with `boolean` is much more elegant.